# Is there a logging system with all kinds of messaging support

Tags: logging, messaging

I have a built a project with about 40 microservices. I want to build a logging/messaging system that allows me to send messages to email/slack/logfile etc. So for example when a user registers, I want to be able to say to the logging/messaging system, send an email or send a slack message or SMS.

Is there such a diverse system out there? Preferably with an api that we can communicate with to allow sending of messages?

Answer (score 0):

I have build similiar logging system using https://www.rabbitmq.com/ and dedicated log processing microservice - it consumed messages from shared logging rabbitmq queue, and, based on priority and type, it either send emails/sms via AWS SNS, saved events into *SQL database and so on.

From existent services - you can probably take a look at loggly.com (as far as i remember, they offered hooks to be executed for kinds of messages.

if you want your system to be self hosted, probably you can achieve similar features with https://www.graylog.org/